# Use of model alias in CI 2.1.4

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can I use model alias in CI 2.1.4. Is there any way ? or I need to update to CI 3 for it. what are the advantage of model alias ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give alias for model with `$this->load->model("user_model","user");`.

Comment: Yes. But will it support to CI version 2.1.4 ?

Comment: yes , it supports. check the user guide of codeigniter 2.1.4

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will check it.